# OSX Doesn't Recognize My External USB Hard-Drive Sometimes

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, external-hard-drive

After ejecting my external HDD, how can I get OSX to detect it without having to take it out of the USB and plugging it back in?

Sometimes plugging back in doesn't work and I have to restart my computer.

Comment: You'll have to give it a few seconds before plugging back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Disk Utility; the drive should be in the left-hand column, ghosted out. Select the disk/volume you ejected and hit the mount button in the toolbar.

If the disk doesn't appear in Disk Utility, your best bet is to yank and reconnect the plug. There are commandline methods, but I don't know them offhand. Look for instructions on mounting a disk from `/dev`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried accessing the external usb hd through terminal. For me it works when I type

```
open /Volumes/[NAMEDISK]
```